# Prevent PWA from being installed

Tags: javascript, service-worker, amp-html, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Is there any way to configure my `manifest.json` to disable the browser popup asking to "install" the site?
I'm using the following JavaScript code to prevent it:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But I need to prevent it also on the AMP version, and I can't run JavaScript code there.

Comment: Why do you link to a manifest from your AMPs if you don't want to support add to homescreen?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by disabling PWA support?

Comment: It's just a business page, I don't want to disturb users with that

Answer (score 8):

Currently, there doesn't appear to be an explicit setting to disable app install.

One workaround is to edit `manifest.json` so that it doesn't meet the required [criteria for app install banner](https://web.dev/install-criteria/#criteria), such as removing `short_name` or `icons` declarations.

Comment: It's a very clever idea, but isn't any other alternative?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an explicit setting to disable app install, so I don't think there's another option. It doesn't sound like you're even using the `short_name` or `icon` if you don't want the app installation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

Another workaround would be to set the `display: 'browser'` option in the `site.webmanifest`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing my `manifest.json` file, I tried removing the link to it from within my `index.html`. I deleted the line:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

This seemed to work fine in my case.